# IOS Facebook SDK 3.1 :: login with fb ios sdk 3.1: Only openActiveSession does in-app login

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm testing the new 3.1 framework. If I call `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler` I can see how an UIAlertView is being popped (as I have facebook login in ios).

However, if I create the session on my own and call `openWithCompletionHandler` I'm redirected to the facebook app or a webview (depending if I have the facebook App installed or not).

Is this broken? Am I missing something?

The reason I don't want to use activeSession, is because I need to set **urlSchemeSuffix**, and I don't see any way of doing that in activeSession (as these are only being set in the init methods of FBSession).

Thank you

Comment: This might help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/#nativeauthdialog

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I still don't understand why it works with activeSession and not with my created sessions. I also see in the docs that when creating your custom session, if you set the urlSchemeSuffix to nil, it will be read from plist file, but they don't say what key it is or I haven't been able to find that. Do you know how to set urlSchemaSuffix in plist file? Thank you!

Comment: Can you use [FBSession setActiveSession:] after you create your session?

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is basically by design, as per the second part of this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/upgrading-from-3.0/ (the SDK is limited to being able to natively request read and publish permissions on separate occasions). What permissions are you asking for with `openWithCompletionHandler`?

Or would it be fair to say that your real question is how to set the suffix for the active session?

Comment: @Ben Flynn: I tried setting my created session as the active Session with that method but it won't work. thank you!

Comment: @James Pearce: I'm only asking for read permissions. However, I ask for the same permissions using activeSession and using my created session, and I see different results, so I don't think is permission related. Like you said, being able to set urlSchemaSuffix in the active session would solve my problem (i would love that), but won't answer the question of why they are behaving differently. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you call setActiveSession? I'm looking at the code for it and don't see how it would fail.

Comment: Ben, nothing happens. If I take the helloFacebook Sample, and change the call to openActiveSession to create my custom session, and setting the same permissions, then it won't do the sdk login and it will redirect to fb app (or webview). I still haven't figure out how to set urlSchemeSuffix with the active session. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through their code, looks like you need to set a specific behavior to get it to use the system account (this is from the FB SDK):

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions
                        allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                  allowSystemAccount:(BOOL)allowSystemAccount
                              isRead:(BOOL)isRead
                     defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
                   completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler {
    // is everything in good order?
    [FBSession validateRequestForPermissions:permissions
                         defaultAudience:defaultAudience
                      allowSystemAccount:allowSystemAccount
                                  isRead:isRead];
    BOOL result = NO;
    FBSession *session = [[[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil
                                           permissions:permissions
                                       defaultAudience:defaultAudience
                                       urlSchemeSuffix:nil
                                    tokenCacheStrategy:nil]
                      autorelease];
    if (allowLoginUI || session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        // we open after the fact, in order to avoid overlapping close
        // and open handler calls for blocks
        FBSessionLoginBehavior howToBehave = allowSystemAccount ?
                                               FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent :
                                               FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView;
    [session openWithBehavior:howToBehave
            completionHandler:handler];
    result = session.isOpen;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I can get it to the system account using openActiveSession, I can not creating my own session. All I need is the ability to set urlSchemeSuffix to the activeSession, or a custom sessions being able to read system facebook account.

Comment: My problem was not using `howToBehave`. Thanks

Comment: can u take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414118/how-to-close-active-session-of-facebook-ios-sdk