# How to get native Facebook login on iOS using SDK 3.1?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I downloaded the new [Facebook iOS SDK 3.1](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/), which promises to have a [native login prompt](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/cfs-ak-ash4/85001/862/488167911203083-/screen-b.png). I ran their sample login app on my iOS 6 device. When I attempted to connect with Facebook, I did not get a native login. Instead, the Facebook app launched - same as the old SDK. Their Facebook login button basically does this:

```
[appDelegate.session 
    openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        [self updateView];
    }
];
```

I thought maybe the sample code isn't calling the right function. So I tried [FBSession](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBSession/#openWithBehavior%3acompletionHandler%3a)'s other login function.

```
[appDelegate.session 
    openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView 
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        [self updateView];
    }
];
```

I tried all possible behaviours and none of them popped up the native login prompt.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It only works for me if I call openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions. Have a look at my post about this http://stackoverflow.com/q/12608008/597652

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you log into Facebook from the iOS settings first?

Once you do that, their example project Scrumptious will use the native login prompt when you try to connect.

Comment: After logging in from Settings > Facebook, I started seeing inline login and permission dialogs. I have a feeling that a lot of users won't figure out how to do this because there's no hint that one should even do it (unless they happen to be computer scientists reading this Stackoverflow post). This is poor design on behalf of Apple and Facebook. A better design would be if you logged in on the Facebook app or website, you would get automatically logged in system wide.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/#nativeauthdialog

Basically you must request basic permissions and read permissions first and then request publish permissions separately.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, and described in the second section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/upgrading-from-3.0/

Basically, you are not able to ask for both read and publish permissions with the iOS6 dialog. Therefore you are more-or-less required to ask for them in a staggered way (e.g. read on first login, and then publish when your app actually needs to publish).

If you insist on using the deprecated method to try and get read & publish at the same time, the SDK has no choice but to return to the web or app-switched technique.