# Prevent iOS native login using Facebook SDK 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am looking for a way to prevent the native Facebook iOS 6.0 login using Facebook SDK 3.1. I ask this because I would like to request read and publish permissions on login. Using the native login only allows you to request read permission.

Comment: What have you thought of / tried ?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608900/how-to-get-native-facebook-login-on-ios-using-sdk-3-1. Basically it seems that if you do request both read and publish permission at open, the SDK will by design not use native login.

Comment: I have tried this Leif; I request both permissions the SDK throws an error. I have found a fix. Instead of splitting the request into two, I use the deprecated method openActiveSessionWithPermissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix for this. To request read and publish permissions on Login, thus preventing the native dialog use the deprecated method, openActiveSessionWithPermissions.